# Java Html Parser that supports XPath Axes?

Tags: java, xpath, axes

Following is a fragment of an html document for which I need to associate the "title" - e.g. FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN - with the text() entry in the first succeeding .

The following xpath works great in python lxml:

```
/td[text()='FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN']/following-sibling::td
```

The doc fragment:

```
   <td>HDFS_BYTES_READ</td>
   <td align="right">4,825</td>
   <td align="right">0</td>
   <td align="right">4,825</td>
 </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN</td>
   <td align="right">415,881</td>
   <td align="right">48,133</td>
   <td align="right">464,014</td>
 </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN</td>
   <td align="right">98,580,205</td>
   <td align="right">2,010</td>
   <td align="right">98,582,215</td>
 </tr>
```

But when I try to do this in Java I am having less success.   I am not sure if there are any java html parsers that can support this.  I am presently using HtmlCleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a preamble: I will indeed look at HtmlUnit as suggested by @Sage.

In the meantime: I have come up with the following solution:

a) HtmlCleaner actually has a DomSerializer for converting to XHtml:

```
public static Document toXhtml(String html) throws ParserConfigurationException {
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    TagNode tagNode = cleaner.clean(html);
    DomSerializer domSerializer = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties());
    return domSerializer.createDOM(tagNode);
}
```

b) At the point that we have XHtml we have plenty of options- just use xalan for example..

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) which has nice `getByXPath()` function. It is a guiless browser. Try to look into examples.

Another one that i use for parsing and like the most is `Jsoup` which has powerful [`select(query)`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) function to do these things easily. Check out its  [selector class](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) documentation. You will find everything you need.